# How to implement "smart" transform: translate?

Tags: javascript, css

I don`t know how i can perform an image check in a block.

That hard to explain, just follow the [link](http://richard.temp.swtest.ru/) and see for yourself. If you scroll down to the cards, wait few seconds you will seen that image go outside from his start point, like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBpO0.png)
and leaves behind itself void.

I want to fix this in such a way that the image could not go beyond its own size.

My JavaScript code:

```js
"use strict";
        var imgArr = document.getElementsByClassName('imgArr');

        [].forEach.call(imgArr, function(item, i, arr) {
            // set variables
            var randValWidth;
            var randValHeight;

            // take the width and height of each image
            var size = {
                'widthImg': arr[i].width,
                'heightImg': arr[i].height
            };

            // set time 
            setInterval(function() {
                // add arguments for tRand() and wRand()
                var randW  = tRand(-size.widthImg/4, size.widthImg/4);
                var randH  = wRand(-size.heightImg/4, size.heightImg/4);
                // start animation
                motionItem();
            }, 2000);

            // find a random value between min and max values
            function tRand(min, max) {
                randValWidth   = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
            };
            function wRand(min, max) {
                randValHeight  = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
            };

            // animate elements
            function motionItem() {
                arr[i].style.transform = 'translate3d(' + randValWidth + 'px,' + randValHeight + 'px,' + 0 + ')';
            };
        });
```

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's just an image and CSS, no need for JavaScript for that. For example, the box contain that image have height 100px but the image have height 200px so they let image full in div and after that use translate the image to image to make it move up and down.

```css
.box {
  width:900px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.img {
  width:90%;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  animation:4s movingUp infinite linear;
  transition:4s;
}
@keyframes movingUp {
  0%{
    transform:translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform:translateY(50px);
  }
  50%{
    transform:translateY(100px);
  }
  75%{
    transform:translateY(-50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img class="img"src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dhue87np7/image/upload/v1508082124/sample.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I need random value for "translate" so i chose js. But thank you for your answer